# Qt : Unable to load TTF file

Tags: c++, qt, truetype, opensuse, fontconfig

I have a Qt-embedded application that I develop in OpenSuse 11.4 where I need to load a TTF font file. However when I call `int QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont()` function, it's returning `-1`.

Upon reading the documentation, I found out that adding application fonts on Unix/X11 platforms without fontconfig is currently not supported.

I checked through YaST whether I have fontconfig installed, and it is installed - but I don't think it's related coz I'm using a qt-embedded library. I'm thinking I gotta have fontconfig support qt-embedded library, but how do I do that?

Does fontconfig even support qt-embedded? Can anybody tell me what's going on?

Comment: Can you confirm with "fc-list" command that your font is actually listed by fontconfig.

Comment: what if it isn't in the list? what's the next step? :)

Comment: find a suitable font in the list, or install the font from yast.
you can even add font paths to the running X and reload it using xrdb. so man xset and man xrdb will tell yu the details.

Comment: by the way, I'm building this app using a 4.5.3 qt-embedded library. And not the QT that came pre-installed in OpenSuse.

Comment: If it is not in the list then qt can not load it ! It is explicitly documented that QT uses fontconfig database to load fonts. I don't think using qt-embedded makes any difference.

Comment: Does fontconfig support qt-embedded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use QPA or [Qt Platform Abstraction](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-Platform-Abstraction) (formerly known as [Lighthouse](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/25/a-lighthouse-by-any-other-name/)). You need to create an implementation (could be made as a plugin or just being used directly) of **QPlatformIntegration** which exposes a custom QPlatformFontDatabase. The trick here is to reuse much of Qt's existing implementation of **QFontconfigDatabase** (which is just as subclass of QBasicUnixFontDatabase).

This is exactly the technique we use for [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) so that it works [headlessly](http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2012/03/pure-headless-phantomjs-no-x11-or-xvfb.html) (without X11) on Linux while still leveraging [Fontconfig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fontconfig) (and thus also [FreeType](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeType)) for text rendering.

Unfortunately I think Qt 4.5 is too old to run Lighthouse. Either move to 4.8 which officialy supports QPA or try to backport Lighthouse.